# Mint: where are installed applets

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation

I want to use an **[alarm applet](http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/alarm-clock-applet)** in Linux Mint 17. I clicked the install button, the software manager popped up and asked for my password. The applet was installed, but it doesn't show in the applet program. I'm fairly new to Mint, so I might be looking in the wrong place.

What can I do to get this applet working?

Comment: What's the "applet program"? You need to add an applet to the panel for it to appear. Also, what desktop environment are you using? Is this Cinnamon? MATE? Gnome? KDE? Something else?

Comment: I´m using Cinnamon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your applet is installed here `/usr/share/applications/alarm-clock-applet.desktop`.

You need a panel though to run it.

Answer (score 9):

I found mine at `~/.local/share/cinnamon/applets`

This is where the applet [Multi-Core System Monitor](http://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/applets/view/79) was stored.

Comment: This is the correct answer for Cinnamon applets.